# Как вызвать метод перед выбором новой строки?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Есть datagridview. При выборе строки грида отображается детализация по данной позиции на форме ниже в textBox - ах. Значения в детализации пользователь может изменить. Есть необходимость запускать метод Temp() при выборе новой строки в гриде. Вопрос в следующем... Как при выборе новой строки и до отображения новых данных в текстбоксах запустить нужный метод Temp()? Есть ли какое событие "ПередВыборомНовойСтроки"?

Comment: А чем это не устраивает? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.90).aspx